# How to set object field in better way in spring app?

Tags: java, json, spring, hibernate

I have entity in spring app below.

```
@Entity(name = "products")
public class ProductModel {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private  UUID id;
    private  String name;
    private  String code;

    private boolean is_group;

    @ManyToOne
    private ProductModel group;
```

and json from frontend app

```
{   "id":"50bfddf4-d5f8-11ed-afa1-0242ac120002",  
    "name":"Phone",   
    "group_id":"7bd886d0-d5f8-11ed-afa1-0242ac120002"
 }
```

this is my controller where I have to find by id productrepo

```
 @CrossOrigin
    @PostMapping(value = "/product/save",produces = "application/json", consumes="application/json")
    void saveProduct(@RequestBody ProductModel productModel){
         var group_id=productModel.getGroup_id();
         if(group_id!=null && group_id.length()>0){
             var group=productRepo.findById(UUID.fromString(group_id)).get();
             if(group!=null){
                 productModel.setGroup(group);
             }
         }
         productRepo.save(productModel);
    }
```

how can I convert group_id from json to ProductModel by any annotation or another settings without using findById () method ?

I expect example of code

Comment: Which attribute of ProductModel  you want o map with the group_id key? I don't see any variable to hold this info in your ProductModel  class.

Comment: I want to set group attibute with ProductModel value found by group_id

Comment: So, in that case it can only populate group_id not complete object ProductModel. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Gaurav Jeswani  I have to write code to find group_id. Is there another way just putting annotion on field and spring itself convert group id into ProductModel by uuid group id contains.
 var group_id=productModel.getGroup_id();
         if(group_id!=null && group_id.length()>0){
             var group=productRepo.findById(UUID.fromString(group_id)).get();
             if(group!=null){
                 productModel.setGroup(group);
             }
         }

Answer (score 0):

With the help of group_id, you can fetch it from the database

example code :

```
@CrossOrigin
@PostMapping(value = "/product/save",produces = "application/json", consumes="application/json")
void saveProduct(@RequestBody ProductModel productModel){
    var group_id = productModel.getGroup_id();
    if(group_id != null && !group_id.isEmpty()){
        UUID groupId = UUID.fromString(group_id);
        Optional<ProductModel> optionalGroup = productRepo.findById(groupId);
        if(optionalGroup.isPresent()){
            ProductModel group = optionalGroup.get();
            productModel.setGroup(group);
        } else {
            // handle error - group not found
        }
    }
    productRepo.save(productModel);
}
```